# IntelliJ IDEA: Detects comparisons (== and !=) of expressions which cannot be the same type

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I use a Scala plugin for IntelliJ IDEA, and I have found a weird behaviour of that plugin. Let me show you a code snippet:

```
def fun: Option[Any] => Int = {
  case Some(x) if x.isInstanceOf[Int] => x.asInstanceOf[Int]
  case None => 0
}
```

Regarding the Scala code, IDEA gives me a warning:

```
Comparing unrelated types
Detects comparisons (== and !=) of expressions which cannot be the same type
```

and it highlights the next statement `x.isInstanceOf[Int]`. I use `isInstanceOf` operator just to determine a type of `x`. Is this a bug of the plugin or I missed something in Scala syntax?

Comment: You want if the number is int then return the number else 0?

Comment: Yes, and I want to do that via pattern matching.

Comment: The "comparing unrelated types" warning of IntelliJ IDEA is not reliable in my experience. I have seen these in several places where clearly the warning was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getOrElse(0)` for this operation.

Edit :

You are geting this error as Some(x) is not same as Int.

But you are making condition direct over here as Some(x) first and then directly checking whether the instance is of Int,so they are basically not of same type(Int and Some)
`case Some(x) if x.isInstanceOf[Int] => x.asInstanceOf[Int]`

To avoid this warning:

You can do something like this if you want to keep it as Option[Any] as Input.

```
def fun(x:Option[Any]):Int = x match {
    case x:Some[Int] => x.get
    case x => 0
}
```

Otherwise,if you know that input will be Option[Int] then 
use it as parameter.

```
def fun(x:Option[Int]):Int = x match {
    case x:Some[Int] => x.get
    case None => 0
}
```

Comment: Good point! But I want to use a `Constructor Pattern`. I have a suspicion that there is some workaround to make it right.

Comment: @Finkelson : Try this.. `def fun:Option[Any]=>Int = {
    case Some(x:Int) => x.asInstanceOf[Int]
    case None => 0
  }`

Comment: Yeap, the warning has gone.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get a similar warning, but something very important you should be aware of is that your code is not "case statement" complete and has potential holes. Should you pass it Some("String") for example, none of your case lines can handle this. Potential fixes:

```
def fun: Option[Any] => Int = {
  case Some(x)  => if (x.isInstanceOf[Int]) x.asInstanceOf[Int] else 0 
  case None => 0
}
```

or

```
def fun: Option[Any] => Int = {
  case Some(x) if x.isInstanceOf[Int] => x.asInstanceOf[Int]
  case Some(other) => 0
  case None => 0
}
```

Comment: I added an additional case `case Some(other) => 0`, but I still see the IDEA warning.